# Overloading C Preprocessor Macros - Discimination Based on Call Syntax

Tags: c++, logging, macros, c-preprocessor

I'm currently working on a cpp logger which aims at displaying the `__FILE__` and the `__LINE__` before each printed message. In my case, we are mostly using 2 methods for printing out: printf-style and std::cout-style. For the moment I have a macros for each style:

```
#define HATFormatFatal(...)    HATLogger::logFormat(HATLogger::LogLevel::FATAL, __FILE__, __LINE__, __VA_ARGS__)
#define HATFormatError(...)    HATLogger::logFormat(HATLogger::LogLevel::ERROR, __FILE__, __LINE__, __VA_ARGS__)
```

etc... and:

```
#define HATStreamFatal   HATLogger::logStream(HATLogger::LogLevel::FATAL, __FILE__, __LINE__)
#define HATStreamError   HATLogger::logStream(HATLogger::LogLevel::ERROR, __FILE__, __LINE__)
```

These macros can be called in the following:

```
HATFormatError("This is an %s message", "ERROR");
HATStreamError << "This is an " << "ERROR" << " message" << std::endl;
```

**I would like to call them with the same name: `HATLogError`. The right macro would be determine at compilation while looking for parenthesis.** So far I've seen some examples showing how it is possible to discriminate the macros by the number of arguments, but nothing that could handle a "non-parenthesis" case.

Does anyone have any idea on how this could be achieved ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest approach would be not overloading the macro at all, but instead having the macro return an object that has both `operator<<` and `operator()` overloaded.  Something like this:

```
class error_logger {
public:
    error_logger(
        HATLogger::LogLevel level,
        char const * file,
        char const * line
    ) : level{level}, file{file}, line{line} { }

    template <typename... T>
    void operator()(T && ... args) {
        HATLogger::logFormat(level, file, line, std::forward<T>(args)...);
    }

    template <typename T>
    HATLogger::logStream operator<<(T && arg) {
        HATLogger::logStream stream{level, file, line};

        stream << std::forward<T>(arg);

        return stream;
    }

private:
    HATLogger::LogLevel level;
    char const * file;
    char const * line;
};
```

(This example assumes `HATLogger::logStream` can be moved.  Adjustments to this example implementation may need to be made based on the details of your code, but the basic approach is what I'm demonstrating here.)

Now you could do:

```
#define HATFormatFatal  (error_logger{HATLogger::LogLevel::FATAL, __FILE__, __LINE__})
```

And then both `HATFormatFatal << ...` and `HATFormatFatal(...)` can be used.

Comment: This works in C++ code. As the question is tagged with both C and C++, how would this be called from C code?

Comment: @ndim I do not believe the C tag is correct. The examples given in the code assume namespaces and/or types with static members, neither of which C has. Nor does C have operator overloading, which renders the whole premise of the question invalid for C.

Comment: This is a very elegant solution !! I'm currently implementing it, no trouble so far ! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Sure for the C tag! I'll just remove it.

Comment: Sorry it was my mistake (and I removed my comment before refreshing the page... double mistake)! Thanks again !

Comment: @nadrino No problem! Glad the approach works for you.